# Vue JS filter by multiple array object items

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have some code which filters an array of objects based on a search input, it filters based on the `search` variable. I'd like to be able to search based on this, and potentially other keys in my object:

```
import HelpGuides from '~/static/help/help-guide.json';

export default {
  head: {
    title: 'Help'
  },
  data () {
    return {
      guides: HelpGuides,
      search: ''
    }
  },
  computed: {

    filteredGuides: function() {
      return this.guides.filter(guide => {
        return guide.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
      })
    }

  }
}
```

Above is my code, which filters the `title` key based on the `search` input, however, each object contains `title`, `tags` and `body`, `tags` is an array, and `body` is a string.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `||` operator to match other keys

```
filteredGuides: function() {
  return this.guides.filter(guide => {
    return guide.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
      || guide.body.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
  })
}
```

Dealing with different types depends on object strcture. Also, remeber you can extract `||` clauses in another function.